# XML.save doesn't update my document

Tags: c#, xml

I'm writing a program that will allow users to upload a photo, add a caption, and save their work. When saving, they will be updating an telerik-rotator that has a xml data source

[image: Solution Explorer]

I have the part where the user can upload a photo working. When they upload a photo, it puts the new photo in the `images` folder. And the telerik control works because `Default.aspx` has the carousel working.

The part I'm struggling with is allowing the user to update `dataSource.xml`

Here is my code behind.

```
protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(NameInput.Text == "")
    {
        generalError.Text = "All fields must be completed";
    }

    try
    {
        //create variables to replace xml
        string photoString = photoDropDown.SelectedItem.Text;
        string caption = NameInput.Text.ToString();
        string location = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("dataSource.xml");

        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.Load(location);
        XmlElement newElement = xml.CreateElement("slide");
        newElement.InnerXml = "<image>" + photoString + "</image><text>" + caption + "</text>";

        xml.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/rotator")[0].AppendChild(newElement);
        xml.PreserveWhitespace = true;
        xml.Save("dataSource.xml");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        generalError.Text = ex.ToString();
        generalError.Visible = true;
        return;
    }


    generalError.Text = "It worked!";
    generalError.Visible = true;

}
```

This throws no errors. So `xml.Save` is saving something. But it is not appending the new node to the xml document. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hmmm, the XML is in your solution, my bet: you're overwriting the file each time you execute the app :D

Comment: I've checked the contents of the XML file. It still has the original nodes I wrote. Nothing has changed in it.

Comment: from where are you checking it? from VS? double-clicking the file in the project?

Comment: Both from visual studio and just from file explorer. I open up my xml document in notepad++ before and after I run my program. It doesn't change.

Comment: But the one in your solution or you did browse to /bin/(debug|release)/dataSource.xml?

Comment: That's the problem, go to where the app is being executed (the path I pasted before)

Comment: I did. there is nothing there. My file isn't being saved there. There are xml files in Bin but they are telerik xml files.

Comment: What datetime of the last change is displayed in the windows explorer? Both before your change using the software and afterwards.

Comment: Figured out my issue. In my xml.save line I passed the location variable instead of the name. Worked perfectly.